# using VBSCRIPT, classic ASP to dynamically style a form

Tags: css, dom, vbscript, asp-classic

I had a quick question. I am trying to get an user-authentication form to load the password or username if a user mis-enters their login information.  The site uses VBSCRIPT along side classic ASP technology and my question revolves around the best way to manipulate the DOM or style a form using the VBSCRIPT. I have no clear idea of the syntax or coding method to attempt something like this.

If you have any knowledge of how to do this, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify "load the password or username if a user mis-enters their login information"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic ASP, the VBScript is running on the *server*, not in the web browser. In classic ASP, you don't actually generate a DOM, you generate an HTML file which is sent to the web browser. The browser turns the HTML into the DOM, but by then, the server is out of the picture. In other words, by the time the DOM exists (in the web browser), VBScript is long gone.

In the situation I think you're describing, the VBScript would need to be modified to generate a different HTML page with a different style form.

Comment: so in 3rd grade level talk (for me) I would have to user VBScript to code a whole new form rather than use the VBScript to modify the form? This kinda makes sense now, I just didn't think thru the usage of the VBScript on the form in respect to it's non-interactivity. thanks for your help.